# Why doesn't a photon state have to be infinite in length?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In all discussions I've seen so far (old quantum theory, semiclassical QM, QFT), when we talk about photon states, we seem to say they have a definite momentum. At the same time, we also say a photon is a particle that is localized in space. These two statements seem contradictory to me, given what I know so far.

In de Broglie's proposition, a photon is supposed to have energy $E = \hbar\omega$ and momentum $p = \hbar k$ ($k = 2\pi/\lambda$). Now in this semi-classical / old quantum theory treatment, the photon has a precise momentum, so doesn't that mean by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle that $\Delta x = \infty$? Even classically, a light wave of definite wavelength would have to be an infinite planewave.

In the second quantization formalism, we can think of a photon as a state of the form $\hat{a}_{\vec{k},\vec{\epsilon}}^{\dagger} | 0\rangle$ (where $\vec{k}$ is a definite wavevector and $\vec{\epsilon}$ is a definite polarization). If I'm not mistaken, the electric and magnetic fields would have nonzero amplitude distribution at every point in the entire quantization volume. But the quantization volume is arbitrary, so it seems there is no sense in which the photon is located in any specific point.

So why do we say photons are localized? It seems like they have to be infinite in size, but that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, for both electrons and photons, we are more secure in the understanding of their momentum eigenstates, that are infinite plane waves that cannot be normalised, than their position eigenstates. The nice property that momentum eigenstates hold, is that they are the free particle's Hamiltonian eigenstates.

(Sidenote: And in the mathematical framework of QFT, the S matrix really needs to be used between Hamiltonian eigenstates, because if you do a small mixture of different energy eigenvalues in any of the initial or final states, the accumulation of infinite phase factors will destroy the calculation's sanity. Just work with Hamiltonian eigenstates first, and the use the postulates of quantum theory to figure out what superpositions of different energy eigenstates are supposed to do.)

Every good textbook will tell you that the real thing has thus to be gotten by wavepackets. Only by superposing many different momentum eigenstates can you hope to normalise the wavefunction, and so forth.

Then you should not have as much difficulty with localising the photon too.

We need to be able to localise the photon because when we detect the photon with a detector, the detector is localised, and so we must be able to say that the photon is at the detector. This is just the most convenient and sensible and natural way to think about it.The photon must also be able to pass through slits, which are localised.

---

Note that both momentum eigenstates and position eigenstates are not normalisable. That is ok. The correct statements of the postulates of quantum theory are that the quantum state lives in Hilbert space, but the eigenstates of the continuous part of observable operators live in rigged Hilbert space. Those non-normalisable eigenstates cannot be realised, but they can be safely used in superpositions to expand any realisable quantum state.

Comment: A photon is not a particle and it doesn't have a state. Only the quantum mechanical ensemble has a state.

Comment: @FlatterMann  *A photon is not a particle* this is your personal theory view. In Mainstream physics the photon is a particle in the standard model of particle physics. In quantum optics it also has a definition. This site is about mainstream physics questions and answers.

Comment: @annav I have long since given up on the duo who love to go around every question mildly related to theoretical issues and spamming their pet theory views. It would be helpful if we can flag comments for non-mainstream physics.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent A good suggestion. I will put it up to the meta physics .

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent currently I cannot find a link for Physics.Meta. I will try later, but maybe they have disabled it.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent found physics.meta by searching, and here is the question I posed https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14416/flagging-non-mainstream-comments-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: I upvoted this post. I think I understand your post, but to be 100% sure, is it accurate to say "real" photons don't have a definite energy?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal thanks. Yes, if you actually detected a photon, you can never be exactly sure of its energy because every detector detects a spread, has uncertainties, etc. Unless you are detecting something that lies in the discrete part of the spectrum of possibilities, detection of anything in the continuous part has to be uncertain. Now, it is important to separate the idea of detector uncertainty from the wavefunction uncertainty. They are different things entirely.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: _Now, it is important to separate the idea of detector uncertainty from the wavefunction uncertainty. They are different things entirely._ - this seems to me to be they key issue here, and perhaps worth expanding upon.

Comment: @JohnRennie, yes, I was struggling to squeeze things into a comment. Any actualisable quantum state lives in Hilbert space and has to be normalisable, whereas the continuum eigenstates live in rigged Hilbert space. The real photon thus must be normalisable wavepackets, with uncertainty spreads in position and momentum bigger than the minimum in Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. This is purely mathematical, a Fourier transform result, nothing to do with experimental uncertainty. The detector uncertainties can only be bigger than what HUP dictates, but is otherwise independent.

Comment: Then we deduce backwards from the detector uncertainties, what wavepackets are the likely ones that are really observed, when a detector clicks. This whole horrible mess is just part and parcel of life as a physicist.

Comment: @annav You can find the definition of "particle" in physics in the first sentence of the first chapter of "Mechanics" by Landau and Lifshitz. The word is defined as the approximation of the motion of a classical body by the motion of its center of mass. That is the only rational definition of "particle" in physics that I am aware of. What Einstein wrote about photons in his 1905 PE paper was that they were supposed to have Newtonian corpuscle properties and he was simply wrong about that. There is no need for us to repeat his mistake over 100 years later. We know better today.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent There is absolutely nothing messy about the definition of photons as irreversibly exchanged amounts of electromagnetic field energy (with an angular momentum of one Planck unit). That definition works in absolutely every physical situation with photons that you will ever encounter. This simplicity is the strength of physics.

Comment: @annav It would be great if semantical side comments unrelated to the original post were reduced.  Stating "A photon is not a particle" is off topic, and has the effect of bringing meaningful discussion to an end.  Who wants to have every sentence picked apart?  I am fairly new to this forum.  Almost every post I participate in ends up as a discussion of the nuances of QFT.  Yet, mainstream QM papers I read rarely touch on such concepts - because they do not contribute to theoretical or experimental considerations.

Comment: @FlatterMann I am genuinely interested in your response: If we try to be charitable, wouldn't it be correct to distinguish between classical particles and quanta that display particle-like properties? Examples of these properties include Compton scattering, localization on detections, and antibunching (in the case of photons). With that in mind, doesn't it make sense to say that when people say "quantum particles" they have this in mind?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal We have been distinguishing quanta from particles for roughly 50 years even at the high school level where we teach that photons are small amounts of energy (and Einstein got it both right and wrong in 1905). Energy never displays object-like properties. It is not an object but a property itself. The entire particle meme is nothing more than a fairly trivial category error. The only question here is why even physicists who can and should know better are still debating something that hasn't needed any debate for generations. If you want a discussion, let's take this to chat.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: we say that photons are localized because a real physical photon detector registers the arrival of a photon at a particular place and time. That's fundamental: the math is stories about this physics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145977/discussion-between-john-doty-and-flattermann).